# How to convert a point 's location to a vector

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I convert a **point's position** to a **vector** which I can then use as the endpoint for an arc node?

I'm using the latest version of blender.

First time using Stack Exchange, so let me know if you need more info.

Clarification:
Is there an ideal way to extract the **Position** of a **vertice/point** into a usable vector to start a "Mesh Line" or "Arc" from?

[image: Update attempt using advice from quellenform]

Comment: It is not quite clear what exactly you mean. The position of a point is a vector. If you are asking how to transfer the position of a certain point, try the node `Sample Index`.

Comment: Hey there, I'm trying to use the `Sample Index` node, but it's not  working.

Comment: If you want to sample the position of the point with the index $1$, you would of course have to put the node `Position` into the input *Value* of the node `Sample Index`, because otherwise nothing would be sampled.

Comment: Thank you @quellenform ! It was the `Position` Node that i was missing.